# Weird behavior of progress bar in homebrew

Tags: homebrew

When I try to install cask/formulae in Homebrew, the progress bar is displayed for several lines instead of one line (you can see in the image).

I've tested with some different casks/formulaes but it still the same.

`brew doctor` gives no error.

May I ask is there any way to fix this?

[image]

Comment: If you open a new Terminal tab and try there, does it happen as well?

Comment: It still happen when I try in a new tab. I also quit Terminal and run the command again but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

My instance of homebrew shows the same behaviour. I noticed that the last character, the percent character doesn't seem to fit in the line any more. Possibly homebrew reads the width of the terminal and calculates the line length slightly wrong, but that's only my speculative take at this point.

Addendum: [This discussion over at github](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/981) seems to confirm what I thought.